# X509Certificate2 has private key not exportable?

Tags: c#, .net, security, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

On Win Server 2008, I can execute the code below, and when I try to export the cert via the MMC GUI, I do not have the option to export the private key as well. However, if I use the GUI to import the cert, I am allowed to export the private key also. What am I missing in my code?

```
string certfile = @"mycert.p12";
SecureString secString = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "password")
{
    secString.AppendChar(c);
}

X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certfile, secString, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My , StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Add(cert);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aha. The key storage flags should be Exportable *and* persisted.

```
X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet
```

Comment: Should that be X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet? I can't seem to see X509KeyStorageFlags.Persisted!

Comment: @caveman_dick, I think so; PersistKeySet works for me.

Thanks for this! It saved me a ton of time.